# THREE.js TrackballControls don't work if camera.position is on the y-axis

Tags: javascript, three.js

In the example below, if camera.position is set to (0,distance,0) where distance is some positive number, the trackball controls don't work properly anymore. Instead there is only zooming if the left mouse button is pressed and the mouse is moved around. Just press the "ALIGN Y" button to see this. The behavior is not observed pressing the "ALIGN X" or "ALIGN Z" button.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>TrackballControls test</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>

        <body>

            <script src='js/libs/inflate.min.js'></script>
            <script src="js/three.js"></script>

            <script src="js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

            <div>
            <button onclick="alignX()" >ALIGN X</button>
            <button onclick="alignY()" >ALIGN Y</button>
            <button onclick="alignZ()" >ALIGN Z</button>
            </div>

            <script>

                var container, camera, controls, scene, renderer, distance;

                init();
                animate();

                function alignX() {controls.reset(); camera.position.set(distance,0,0);}
                function alignY() {controls.reset(); camera.position.set(0,distance,0);}
                function alignZ() {controls.reset(); camera.position.set(0,0,distance);}

                function init() {

                    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000 );
                    distance = 2.2;
                    camera.position.set(0,0,distance);

                    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

                    controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
                    controls.zoomSpeed = 5;
                    controls.panSpeed = 2;

                    controls.noZoom = false;
                    controls.noPan = false;

                    controls.staticMoving = true;
                    controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

                    scene = new THREE.Scene();

                    // light

                    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
                    camera.add( ambientLight );

                    var light = new THREE.PointLight();
            light.position.set( 2, 2, 2 );
            camera.add( light );

                    scene.add( camera );

                    // objects

                    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors });

                    var ico = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry( 0.8, 0 );
                    for ( var i = 0; i < ico.faces.length; i ++ ) {
                        var face = ico.faces[ i ];
                        face.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
                    }
                    var bert = new THREE.Mesh( ico, material );
                    scene.add( bert )

                    // renderer

                    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
                    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                    document.body.appendChild( container );
                    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

                }

                function onWindowResize() {

                    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                    controls.handleResize();

                }

                function animate() {

                    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                    controls.update();
                    renderer.render( scene, camera );

                }

            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try controls.object.position.set(...) instead of camera.position.set(...)

Comment: Reopened your three.js [post](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10161).

Comment: With the suggestion from @prisoner849 I get the same behavior.